# Remove The Blank Spaces

Tags: mysql

I was trying to figure a MYSQL query in PHP Admin to only show rows without any blank spaces. I can write a query to not show blank spaces in one column but in two columns I am having and issue, and three columns as shown below.

```
Name          Phone                Email
Tom           800-555-1212         ttest@hotmail.com
Mike                               mtest@hotmail.com
John          800-666-1212        
              800-777-1212         atest@hotmail.com
Kate          800-888-1212
Sue           800-555-2222         stest@hotmail.com
Phil                               ptest@hotmail.com
```

To filter out the blank spaces so it will be this way:

```
Name          Phone            Email
Tom          800-555-1212      ttest@hotmail.com
Sue          800-555-2222      stest@htomail.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check that there isn't any empty column: `<> ''`

```
SELECT Name, 
       Phone, 
       Email
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  Name <> ''
AND    Phone <> ''
AND    EMail <> '';
```

Comment: If, by "empty", you mean `NULL`, then a different syntax is needed.